# jQuery .each() function shows always last link in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some links on my page and everyone is linked to a popup which should load an `iframe` with a dynamic source attribute. The `iframe` has a div called 'pholder' in which the `iframe` should be loaded. So on every link should be another `iframe`. But it isn't. It's always the same. To be exactly, it's always the last link and I don't know why. Here you can see the HTML of the popup:

```
<div id="toPopup3">
    <div id="videoContainer">
        <div id="activeVideo">
            <div class="pholder"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!--toPopup3 end-->
```

I have to say that my links all have the class `toPopup3 link + e`. `e` is the maximum of Videos (0-23). So I use this code to add the `iframe`:

```
var videoLink;
var split;

$('[class^="topopup3 link"]').each(function(){
    videoLink = $(this).attr('href');
    split = videoLink.split("/");
});

$('.pholder').html('<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/'+split[3]+'?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&color=fc6626" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>');
```

So it always shows the last source in the `iframe` and I don't get rid of it. Can someone help me?

Here is a link to the live version of the page: [Live Page](http://dev.jantofilm.ch/). The problem occurs at 'film production'. I also put `console.log(split[3]);` in the code to see the order of the links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: given a little more insight into your goal, I think it would be better to accomplish this with a clickhandler:

```
$('[class^="topopup3 link"]').on('click', function(){
    var videoLink = $(this).attr('href');
    split = videoLink.split("/");
    $('.pholder').html('<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/'+split[3]+'?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&color=fc6626" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>');
    // may need to show the iframe modal or whatever here
});
```

Your not doing anything with the `split` variable until you are **done** looping, therefore the value will be the last one. If you are wanting to use each value, you need to move your subsequent `$('.pholder')...` code into your `each` block

Comment: That's because you are updating all `.pholder`s the same way each time. If it is a one-to-one ratio, use `.each(function(index){..` and `$('.pholder').eq(index)...`

Comment: Hmm okay, it changes something. Did you see the live page? If yes, you see that there are 4 pages with 5 or 6 links. And with `.eq(index).html()` it always loads the first item of the last page. I noticed that the links are messed up

Comment: I think I'm confused about your goal here, is there one iframe or is it one iframe per one link?

Comment: Perhaps I explain it in another way: All the links are videos on vimeo. And I don't want to link it to vimeo. Instead I want to open the videos in a popup which has an iframe. Foreach video a popup with an iframe in it

Comment: My man! With the click event it works perfectly! Thank you very much :)